# Count duplicates in huge text files collection

Tags: java, sorting, text, corpus

I have this collection of folders:

```
60G ./big_folder_6
52G ./big_folder_8
61G ./big_folder_7
60G ./big_folder_4
58G ./big_folder_5
63G ./big_folder_2
54G ./big_folder_9
61G ./big_folder_3
39G ./big_folder_10
74G ./big_folder_1
```

Each folder contains 100 txt files, with one sentence per line. For example, the file ./big_folder_6/**001.txt**:

```
sentence ..
sentence ..
...
```

Each file in the folder is between 4 and 6 GB (as you can see from the totals reported above) with 40-60 million of sentences more or less. One single file fits in memory.

I need to deduplicate and count the sentences **globally unique**, so as to obtain a new collection of files where the lines are counted:

```
count    ...unique sentence...
```

The collection is huge.

My first implementation (using Java) was a "merge sort" approach ordering the lines in a new collection of 500 files (dispatching each line in the right file using the first N characters), then order and aggregate duplicates on the single files.

I know it is a wordcount map-reduce problem but I would prefer to avoid it. The question is: am I using the right approach to solve this kind of problem or I should consider other tool/approach beside MapReduce?

Comment: Why don't you try hadoop? If not, you can start proper multiple threads to read from each file and each thread do its best to count it.

Comment: Do you need to dedupe and count across all files and all directories?

Comment: Can we assume that the unique lines will fit in memory or does it need to be done in a way that the final result is larger than available memory?

Comment: try fork join java framework of java

Comment: Could you post a small example of input and expected output. It's not clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

You mean delete duplicated lines of each file? or among all files?

in any case, you cant read the whole file, you need to read line by line or a memory exception will be thrown. Use BufferedReader (example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/bufferedreader_readline.htm)), use a map storing the string with the count of the repeated line as a value, when you read a line, put in the map incrementing the value if it exist.

After read the file, write all the lines and theirs counts to a new file and release memory.

**UPDATE 1**

the problem is that you have a lot of gigas. So you cant keep in memory each line because it can thrown a memory exception, but at the same time you have to keep them in memory to quickly validate if they are duplicated. What comes to may mind is instead of having a string representing the key value, put a hash of the string (usgin string.toHash()), and when it was the first, write it to the new file, but flush every 100 lines or more to lower the time writing to the disk. After you processed all the files and write unique lines in the file and you have only integers in the map (hashcode of the string as a key and count as a value), you start reading the file containing only unique lines, then create a new file writing the line and the count values.

Comment: Exactly, I need to deduplicate among all files. In the way you described I would duduplicate only in one file, the one that fits in memory.